# R Shiny - sliderInput shows repeated values

Tags: r, shiny, slider

I have a `sliderInput` widget that works with a range of values that I update dynamically on my server.

`sliderInput`'s step argument is specified as being equal to 1, however the numbers shown in the slider appear repeated, e.g., `1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4`.

[image]

#### ui.r code

```
sliderInput(inputId="numberOfElements",
                                        label = "Number of elements to delete",
                                        #values updated dynamically on server.r
                                        min = 1, 
                                        max = 5, value = 1, step = 1
                                        )
```

#### server.r code

```
updateSliderInput(session,
                  "numberOfElements",
                   max = elems-1,
                   step = 1)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Very strange, I tested the code and it works normally besides the exception that the spacing gets thrown off when changing the max and having the slider not at zero (fixed by setting `value=0` in `updateSliderInput`). I used a `selectInput` as my "elems" for testing purposes, can you show what creates `elems` for you?

Comment: I am actually realizing I have found the same bug as you as the spacing is off but also there are repeats. I believe you have found a bug, I think they are working on it here https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2159

Comment: I am linking this question to the bug thread if that is alright with you.

Comment: @Chabo, yes that's alright with me. Thank you.

Comment: As an update to this issue, it is indeed a new bug the devs were unaware of, now referenced here https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2254 . Hopefully will be fixed by v1.3